# Manage token expiry after login

Tags: android, authentication, token

I am building an application in which when a user logs in, a json is received which has a token, login time and expiry time of token.

Now I want to show the login screen only if the token has expired, else i want the user to move to the next screen.

I thought of matching the device's clock time with the expiry time but in that particular case, if the device has a wrong time, the app will move with an expired token.

Please help what else can I do.

Comment: sir, what i think is to create a custom timer countdown in a service.. and notify user when its time..

Comment: @Elltz, will this countdown timer run even if the app is closed? This will be needed so as to change the shared preference value for login.

Comment: yeah,Sir, services are part of your app but they run in the background.. so yes its gonna run even if the app is not in the backstack..google android services..the official documentation and much elaboration is there..hope it helps you, Sir

Comment: @Elltz, will try implementing it and then get back to you.

Comment: You can try to log in, and if you receive 401 Unauthorized, then the token is expired. Then you can show the login screen.